# drawable/assets can you have a subfolder in that directory?

Tags: android

Trying to add a group of images which are in folders. I seem to notice that I can only use them if they're not in subfolders. Is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create subdirectories in a resource directory. `res/drawable-hdpi/` can hold images, but not directories of images, for example.

`assets/` can have whatever directory structure you want.

Comment: So to clarify, can I have res/assets/images? When I try to use them in the xml layout viewer, they don't seem to be recognised?

Comment: @Bushes: "can I have res/assets/images?" -- no, because there is no resource type named `res/assets/`. You can have an `assets/` directory as a peer of `res/`. Assets are not resources.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say res/drawable/assets/images

Comment: @Bushes: Please re-read my answer. You cannot have `res/drawable/assets/images`, because `res/drawable/assets/` is a directory, and you cannot have a directory inside of a resource directory.

Comment: Sorry I just understood what you meant. I previously forgot that I added the assets folder myself and thought it was a standard resources directory.